Bokeh, how do i remove datetimes without corresponding values?
hope you are doing well, i would like to render a chart without the long lines present, which correspond to the values that do not have the corresponding pair.
Here is the function that is generating my chart, hope i does not scary you:
def get(self, request):
        user=request.user
        historical_me=FinancialInstrument.objects.all()
        form = self.form_class(historical_me=historical_me)
        
        retrive=HistoricalData.objects.all()
        get_symbol=retrive.filter(instrument__symbol="BTUSD").order_by('datetime')
        fields=get_symbol.values('datetime','opening_price','closing_price','min_price','max_price','volume')
        df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(fields)
        
        x_values = [key.datetime for key in get_symbol]
        y_values = [float(key.opening_price) for key in get_symbol]
        
        source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(dater=x_values,pricer=y_values))
        plot = figure(title="New title", width=780, height=400,
                      x_axis_label="Date", y_axis_label="Max Price", x_axis_type="datetime")
        plot.line(x='dater',y='pricer', source=source,line_width=3)
        
        unique_dates = HistoricalData.objects.order_by('datetime').values_list('datetime', flat=True).distinct()

        plot.line(x='datetime', y='opening_price', source=source, line_width=3)

        plot.toolbar.autohide = True

        script, div = components(plot)
        if user.is_authenticated:
            return render(
                request,
                self.template_name,
                {
                    'form':form,
                    'days_of_month': [i for i in range(1,32)],
                    'script':script,
                    'div':div,
                })

        return redirect('home')

This is the chart it produces, i need an approach to suppress those long lines, which correspond to the dates that do not have a corresponding value.


The solution is to add NaN to all dates without a valid value to your DataFrame, because the line renderer interpolates between given data points. If there is a NaN value, nothing is plotted. In your case one option is to add a simple frequency using pandas resample() function.
See the minimal example below:
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

data = {
    'datetime': ['2024-04-15', '2024-04-16', '2024-04-19', '2024-04-20'],
    'opening_price': [1,  1, -1, -1],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)

# the one line which adds a frequency and to all not know dates the value `NaN`
df = df.resample('1D').mean()

p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', x_axis_label='date', y_axis_label='change')
p.line(x='datetime', y='opening_price', source=df, line_width=3)
show(p)




without resample
with resample









If we compare the two printed DataFrames, you can see whats changed.
This is the DataFrame without the resample call.
            opening_price
datetime                 
2024-04-15              1
2024-04-16              1
2024-04-19             -1
2024-04-20             -1

And this the changed one.
            opening_price
datetime                 
2024-04-15            1.0
2024-04-16            1.0
2024-04-17            NaN
2024-04-18            NaN
2024-04-19           -1.0
2024-04-20           -1.0

Keep in mind that the line call needs at least two consecutive data points to draw a line. A single point will be invisable using line. The circle renderer has a different behavior.
